# How to cast youtube video url from android app

Tags: android, youtube, chromecast, google-cast

Unable to cast youtube video URL from my Android application through Chromecast whereas I successfully played other video content from my server.

Here is the code:

```
private void startVideo() {
        MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata( MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE );
        mediaMetadata.putString( MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, getString( R.string.video_title ) );

        MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(
                "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zy0cCn7F7mw")
                .setContentType( video/mp4 )
                .setStreamType( MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED )
                .setMetadata( mediaMetadata )
                .build();
        try {
            mRemoteMediaPlayer.load( mApiClient, mediaInfo, true )
                    .setResultCallback( new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult( RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult mediaChannelResult ) {
                            if( mediaChannelResult.getStatus().isSuccess() ) {
                                mVideoIsLoaded = true;
                                mButton.setText( getString( R.string.pause_video ) );
                            }
                        }
                    } );
        } catch( Exception e ) {
        }
    }
```

I tried the MIME type with "video/webM" but not worked. Please help.

Comment: can you share your code? It quite impossible to try to help you without saw what you are doing.

Comment: I am having same issue can anyone give some solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to cast an HTML web page that has the YouTube player on it rather than an actual video file itself, which won't work ... the content of the MediaInfo has to be the direct URL to the video stream.

What's more, you won't be able to get that for a YouTube video; all YouTube videos must be played via the YouTube player (on desktop or mobile).

Comment: So you mean to say there is no way to cast youtube link directly from the app. 
I think its possible if we design custom HTML cast application for device which can handle youtube links & can play in <iframe>
Please let me know your views.

Comment: Well, that's different ... that isn't casting the video, but launching the sender and telling the sender to load the YouTube player API with the right video ID. That would definitely be possible, but you'd have to customize your receiver to be able to handle custom messages (so your sender can tell it what the videoID is), as well as set up your own playback controls (since the interface for the YouTube Player API is quite a bit different than that of an HTML5 video element). But with a custom receiver and a customMessageBus, you'd be in business.